# How to include a BuildConfig or resource in network_security_config.xml

Tags: android, localhost, android-build-type, android-network-security-config

To make http-API calls on localhost in Android I needed to add a network-security-config to define my local IP address. Of course, the local IP address is different for each developer, so I put this value in `gradle.properties` so everyone can override this themselves. However, I haven't found out how to include that value in the `network-security-config.xml` file. I tried it by creating a `buildConfigField` or `resValue` in `build.gradle`, but both don't seem to work. What can I do?

network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <!-- We are allowed to call localhost on http instead of https:
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted -->
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">LOCALHOST</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

app/build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "LOCALHOST", localIpAddress
        resValue "string", "LOCALHOST", localIpAddress
    }
}
```

gradle.properties

```
localIpAddress="IP_ADDRESS_HERE"
```

Any other solutions how to gracefully include my local IP address in `network_security_config.xml` are welcome too!

Comment: Did you figure this one out? Im in the same boat.

Comment: Nope, I'm not even on that project anymore, so can't tell..